# Getting invalid SQL syntax upon executing stored procedure via DB2 CLI

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I am working on a stored procedure to update values in a couple of tables in one go. I am getting `CLI0118E  Invalid SQL syntax.` during the execution. However, I am not able to find the issue with my stored procedure as I am not quite familiar with the whole stored procedure rules. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYPROCNAME(IN VAL1 VARCHAR(255),IN VAL2 VARCHAR(255),IN VAL3 VARCHAR(255),IN VAL4 VARCHAR(255))
  LANGUAGE SQL
  BEGIN ATOMIC
    UPDATE SCHEMA1.TABLE1 SET col1=VAL2, col2=VAL3, col3=VAL4 WHERE col1=VAL1;

    UPDATE SCHEMA2.TABLE1 SET col1=VAL3, col2=VAL3, col3=VAL4 WHERE col1=VAL1;

    FOR v AS
      SELECT col1 FROM SCHEMA2.TABLE2 WHERE col2=VAL1
        DO
          UPDATE SCHEMA2.TABLE3 SET col2=VAL2 WHERE col1=v.col1 AND col3='<<value>>';
          UPDATE SCHEMA2.TABLE3 SET col2=VAL3 WHERE col1=v.col1 AND col3='<<value2>>';
    END FOR;
  END
  @
```

In the FOR statement, I even tried like this `FOR v AS cur1 CURSOR FOR`

Used this to compile the procedure first -- `db2 -td@ -vf myprocname.db2`

Then, tried executing the procedure using -- `db2 call MYPROCNAME 'val1','val2','val3','val4'`

Also, tried the execution in diff combinations like `db2 call MYPROCNAME ('val1','val2','val3',val4')`, `db2 call MYPROCNAME("val1","val2","val3","val4")`, etc...

If I use `()` in the db2 call, I get the `bash: syntax error near unexpected token ('` error.

PS: I am using db2 11.5

Comment: `db2 "call MYPROCNAME ('val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4')"`

Comment: Awesome, that did the job :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment to my question above, running the following `db2 "call MYPROCNAME ('val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4')"` fixes the issue